# What word/phrase means "the feeling of the time/era"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, loanwords

I think I recall encountering a phrase that means roughly "the characteristic feeling of a particular historical time". For example, this word/phrase could be applied to the French Revolution or the Renaissance.

This may well be a French (or other language) phrase but it was used in English. Something like mise-en-scène or milieu, but referring specifically to the context of a historical period/moment in time.

Comment: Not as common as it used to be, but still the most likely phrasing: [***the spirit of the age***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+spirit+of+the+age&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20spirit%20of%20the%20age%3B%2Cc0) But if you want a "foreign word imported into English", consider the German [***zeitgeist***.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeitgeist)

Comment: "Period" is also useful in this context, as in "period piece" or "mores of the period".

Comment: ...actually, according to Google Books, [***zeitgeist** has overtaken **spirit of the age***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+spirit+of+the+age%2Czeitgeist&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) in written English over the past couple of decades. Probably not in *spoken* contexts, though.

Comment: There are various French phrases "esprit de..." or "esprit du..." meaning "spirit of..." ("Esprit du temps" seems to be the translation of "Zeitgeist".) I don't think any are particularly common in English.

Comment: Yes, of course, it is zeitgeist :) If you make that an answer I can accept it (I hope).